# Win XP: put harddrive in new computer

Tags: windows, windows-xp, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it safe to move system disk to a new computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/174186/is-it-safe-to-move-system-disk-to-a-new-computer)

I want to move my exisiting harddrive which has windows XP on it to a new box which has better hardware (mb, processor, mem, etc).

Can I simply move the drive and everything will work or will there be some problems?

Comment: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/229961-35-motherboard-change-install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's highly unlikely that it will work first time. You'll probably have to boot into Safe Mode and install any nessecary drivers and see if it works. Your XP installation will also detect the different hardware and will ask your to re-activate your XP license.

Answer (score 1):

As @tombull89 mentions, you will likley have some work.  In addition to his comments, it may simply fail to boot at all and safe mode will not be an option.  Storage drivers could be the big challenge.

Applications like Symantec System Recovery will allow the old drive to be imaged and restored to different hardware.  It guides you through the diver issues and allows them to be installed before booting.

In any case, I would be sure to have everything backed up before doing the switch.